# Start Kubuntu from within Debian

Tags: kubuntu, virtualization, debian

My employer has provided me with a laptop running Debian Stretch Unstable which is allowed to be used for private purposes. I have installed Kubuntu 16.10 on a seperate partition and everything is doing fine. However, I would like to be able to run my private Kubuntu-Environment not just by booting into it, but also from within the main Debian system, just like running it in a virtual machine.

Is this possible?
If so: How?

Comment: Well, convert it to a virtual machine. It might be possible (depending on the virtualization software you use) to grant a VM direct access to the Ubuntu partition on the disk, so that you don't need to convert it into a virtual disk image, but I'm not sure how well Ubuntu will accept booting both in a VM and on bare metal alternately. Should be possible somehow though, if you invest enough time and thought.